# d3, set stroke attribute of single rect element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a heat map, and I've drawn rect elements as seen below. I'm trying to set a stroke color/width of each individual rect element on mouseover. I've used mouseover to display a hidden div tooltip, for example, but I can't seem to be able to select the rect element. I've tried using the event variable, as in  `.on('mouseover', (e,d) => e.attr('stroke','black'))`, but I can't get it working.

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(mv)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', (w- 2*padding)/(mv.length/12))
      .attr('height', (h-(2*padding))/12)
      .attr('x', d => xScale(d.year))
      .attr('y', d => yMap(d.month))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving each element a class and setting a `.class:hover` selector in CSS -- a bit obvious after all